# Correct Model Data Structure for a Movie site using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I need to save a bunch of people that a related to a movie without duplication.

Let's take the movie *Inglourious Basterds* as an example.

Here *Quentin Tarantino* has a bunch of roles.

- Director
- Writer
- Actor

Here is an example of an rspec test

```
Movie.find_by_title("Inglourious Basterds").actors.map(&:name).should include("Quentin Tarantino")
Movie.find_by_title("Inglourious Basterds").writers.map(&:name).should include("Quentin Tarantino")
Movie.find_by_title("Inglourious Basterds").directors.map(&:name).should include("Quentin Tarantino")
```

How should I set up the relations between the models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly simple set of models for rails to do.

```
rails g model movie name:string
rails g model person name:string
rails g model movie_role movie:belongs_to person:belongs_to role:string
```

And for the model associations:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_roles
  has_many :movies, :through => :movie_roles
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  %w(actor director writer).each do |type|
    base = "#{type}_movie_roles"
    has_many base, :conditions => { :role => type }, :class_name => 'MovieRole'
    has_many type.pluralize, :through => base, :source => :person
  end
end
```